# Trying to do two Parse PFQueries but getting error - in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently doing two PFQueries at once, one which is a `PFUser.query` and one which is a standard object query. These are both trying to execute roughly at the same time. I get no errors in the code until it runs it says:

`'Cannot do a comparison query for type: Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl'`

I can only assume this is because I am trying to do two different queries at once?

Can somebody add some input into what it means a bit more and how maybe to overcome it?

the code I have used for both queries is:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Traits")
            query.whereKey("name", equalTo: self.names)
            var waveUsers = query.findObjects()

            if waveUsers != nil {

                self.profile.waves.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for waveUser in waveUsers{


                    self.profile.waves.append(waveUser["waves"] as Int)
                    }
                }
```

and the PFUser Query:

```
 var query = PFUser.query()
                query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)
                query.limit = 20
                var users = query.findObjects()

                if users != nil {

                    self.profile.names.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.images.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.genders.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.locations.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.status.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.rStatus.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                    self.profile.age.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)


                    for user in users {

                       {
                            self.profile.names.append(user["name"] as Int)
                            self.profile.images.append(user["image"] as NSData)
                            self.profile.genders.append(user["gender"] as NSString)
                            self.profile.locations.append(user["location"] as PFGeoPoint)
                            self.profile.rStatus.append(user["relationship"] as NSString)
                            self.profile.age.append(user["age"] as NSInteger)
                            self.profile.status.append(user["status"] as NSString)

                            self.appsTableView.reloadData()

                            user.save()
                    }
                }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: There are both done inside two different functions.

Comment: self.profile.names, is this initialised as an Int or an NSString/String? It seems strange that its having an Int assigned to it.

Comment: It's set as an int. the Query runs fine on its own. It's when they are ran together it's crashes

Comment: Narrowed it down a bit more. It is only the first Query that is causing the problem. and it appears to be the line: `query.whereKey("name", equalTo: self.names)` . The `self.names` is an array, would the effect the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test whether the "name" col can be found in your `self.names` array, then use `containsAllObjectsInArray:`

`equalTo` operates on single objects (it can test for a single object's presence in an array type column, but you're attempting the other way around).

**EDIT** - Lets say you have an array of strings, and you'd like to find objects whose string column an be found in the array...

```
// find people in the People class who were SNL cast members
var array = ["belushi", "akroyd", "radner"];
var queries = [];

// assume underscorejs
_.each(array, function(name) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("People");
    query.equalTo("lastName", name);
    queries.push(query.find());
});
Parse.Query.or(queries).then(function() {
    var snlCastMembers = _.toArray(arguments);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that has got rid of the error now. Although the `waveUsers` is now coming back as nil. What I want to do is query all the `"name"` objects from parse which is equal to the same objects as `self.names`. I then want to append them to the array `self.profile.waves`?? Not sure why `waveUsers` is nil thou?

Comment: The way to go there is make N queries, one for each name in your self.names array.  Run them all together using Parse.Query.or().  You'll get an array result, and you can addObjectsFromArray: to self.profile.waves (assuming its mutable).

Comment: Sorry what is an N query? and is there no way to check the equivalent of `equalTo` but with an array of results instead of just one singular result. As I don't think your suggestion will work as I don't know the exact name what I am searching for.

Comment: I just meant an array of queries of length N (some number).  Pls see edit to demonstrate using Query.or().  It assumes underscorejs but just to do a loop and to create an array from var args passed to the completion block.

Comment: Reading back in your question, you might also want to check out promises.  Your findObjects() happens asynchronously, so the users variable will not be initialized as you expect.  See how I used .then() in the code just added?

Comment: Sorry is that swift you have used? as I am still new and learning and that looks very Alien to want I have been doing recently? Looks like Javascript...

Comment: Whoops.  Javascript.  Sorry.  I can't speak swift very well.  I can change to objective c?

Comment: That would easier then javascript so I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71109/discussion-between-danh-and-michael-willis).